# How can I customize the behaviour of a Rust generic function for a specific type?

Tags: rust, serde

I'd like to create a generic function that queries an API an optionally parses its output as JSON. The issue I run into is that `serde_json::from_str<()>("")`, which gets called when the generic function's return type is unit, returns an error.

Here is a (slightly contrived) minimal example that reproduces the problem:

```
use reqwest::blocking::Client; // 0.11.18
use anyhow::Result; // 1.0.71
use url::Url; // 2.4.0
use serde_json::from_str; // 1.0.102
use serde::Deserialize; // 1.0.171

fn get<T: for<'a> serde::Deserialize<'a>>(client: &Client, url: Url) -> Result<T> {
    let response = client.get(url)
        .send()?
        .error_for_status()?;
    let text = response.text()?;
    let result = from_str::<T>(&text)?;
    Ok(result)
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    height: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Planet {
    name: String,
    climate: String,
}

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let client = Client::new();

    // Query a Person
    let luke = get::<Person>(&client, Url::parse("https://swapi.dev/api/people/1/")?)?;
    println!("Luke: {:?}", luke);

    // Query a Planet
    let tatooine = get::<Planet>(&client, Url::parse("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/")?)?;
    println!("Tatooine: {:?}", tatooine);

    // Contrived example: make a request for which we want no
    // output. In the real world it is not a HTTP GET request but
    // POST, PUT, ...
    get(&client, Url::parse("https://swapi.dev/api/vehicles/4/")?)?; // <- Error here
    Ok(())
}
```

For this example, a simple solution is to create a separate function (e.g. `get_no_result`) that does not parse the output of the request. In C++, the most elegant approach would be to specialize the function template but it is not possible today in Rust.

What is the most "rustic" solution to this in Rust?

Comment: I'm confused. If you want to handle the parse error, then handle the parse error. The function is returning a [`serde_json::Result`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/type.Result.html), not panicking. You should just do it before erasing all error information into `anyhow`, because after that point there's not much meaningful you can do to an error other than log it and move on.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo, I don't want to handle the parse error in the general case. The `get` function as shown does what I want for all types except `()`. For this specific case, I need `get` to return without attempting to parse anything, because `serde_json::from_str` (understandably) doesn't support parsing into `()`.

Comment: Can you control the output of the endpoint? Serde can deserialize `()`. It writes it as `null` in JSON, so if you can have your endpoint output the string `null`, you're golden. Outside of that, this is a situation where [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) would be useful.